# php in sublime text 2

Tags: php, sublimetext2

Hello I wanted to add system build in sublime text 2 to learn php.
PHP works on localhost so everything should be ok.

My build system looks like:

```
{
 "cmd": ["php", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.php"
}
```

There are errors when I press ctrl+b. Maybe anyone know where problem is?

```
[Errno 2] no such a file or directory
[cmd:  [u'php', u'/var/www/test2.php']]
[dir:  /var/www]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/adam/.rvm/bin]
[Finished]
```

Comment: This would probably be better asked on the sublime forums because it isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - this is perfectly on-topic, we get questions like this all the time in the various sublime tags. Sublime is "a piece of software primarily used for programming" and this is in relation to its build systems.

Comment: @user3564663 if you open Terminal and run `which php` at the command prompt, what is the output? Have you actually installed the php binary package on your system?

Comment: @MattDMo my point was more that it would probably get a quicker/better response at a forum for the specific product, not that it was off topic (even though I guess I did say that).